# Adding Text to a ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, text

I have a problem with adding text to a ListLogLinearPlot plot. The text just doesn't show up anywhere. If I use the normal ListPlot, the text coordinates go perfectly wherever I want them to:

```
Text["a",{x,y}]
```

Using LogLog plot, I add the extra Log@ and it also works fine

```
Text["a",Log@{x,y}]
```

But there is no way I can figure out how to correctly place some text onto a ListLogLinearPlot. I googled the problem extensively to no avail. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Only the abscissa is logarithmic, so:

> ```
>  ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}], 
>  Epilog -> {Text["Hello", {Log[1.2], 3.0}]}]
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent too much time on this...

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Table[{10^n, n}, {n, 1, 5}];

ListLogLinearPlot[
 data,
 Epilog -> Table[Text[#[[i]], {Log @ #[[i]], i + 0.5}], {i, 1, Length @ #}] &[First /@ data],
 PlotRangePadding -> {1, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]